# audio streaming between two interfaces (server and client)

Tags: java, streaming

I want to create a audio streaming application where a client connects to the server ip (in the same computer or may be different computer) and they can have a audio chatting.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are going to use Java for this app development. Please consider the following hints :
1. Use AudioInputStream class in javax.sound.* package to get sound input.
2. Use DatagramPacket class in java.net.* packcage to send the bytes of the audio input to send it to the desired destinantion, be it client or server.
3. Assemble the packets
OR
Create a wav file from captured audio and send it to the destination using TCP 
3. Use AudioOutputStream to play the recvd audio bytes.